# QML: Popup anchors.centerIn blurs content (no anchors.alignWhenCentered)

Tags: qt, popup, qml, qt5, qtquick2

The QML type `Popup` is not of type `Item`. Because of that the only `anchors`-property that can be set is `anchors.centerIn`.

Usually you could set `anchors.alignWhenCentered: true` but that's not possible for a popup causing my content to blur (because the position is not rounded to pixels).

Is this a bug in Qt or am I doing something wrong? I guess a workaround would be to calculate the position myself but I feel like there is something wrong with Qt here or another easy way to do this.

Example code to get a blurry popup (you need to look very closely, I added a screenshot below as an example):

```
Popup {
    anchors.centerIn: Overlay.overlay
}
```

Button inside Popup **without** `anchors.centerIn`:
[image: not-blurry button]

Button inside Popup **with** `anchors.centerIn`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm still sure this is a bug in Qt but here is a workaround.
This will just manually calculate the position of the Popup and round to whole pixels:

```
Popup {
    x: ~~(Overlay.overlay.width / 2 - width / 2)
    y: ~~(Overlay.overlay.height / 2 - height / 2)
}
```